# SQL Query, bring data between 2 dates with limitation

Tags: sql, loops, date, difference

In SQL, I am going to write a query which insert all data between 2 dates and also I want to bring then in a 1000 batch but since the number of data between those days are more than  my limitation I was going to write a loop which makes the smaller period to bring the data.
here is my code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = CAST('2021-06-02 01:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = CAST('2021-06-23 01:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)

DECLARE @RealRowCount INT = (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(@@ROWCOUNT) OVER() FROM GetReport (
                         @StartDate, @EndDate))
DECLARE @TransactionCount INT = (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionCount FROM GetReport (
                             @StartDate, @EndDate))

WHILE @RealRowCount < @TransactionCount
BEGIN
DECLARE @DiffDate INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate))
SET @EndDate =  DATEADD(DAY, @DiffDate/2 ,@StartDate)

SELECT *,@StartDate, @EndDate  FROM GetReport (@StartDate, @EndDate)
END
```

PS: I was thinking about find the middle of the period of date and then change them into the new EneDate and StartDate but there is problem here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create another table to put Dates and if this table has any rows I can get 'EndDate', but if it has not any records I simply just use the date that I specified.
AccSync is the table that I insert details of my records and AccTransformation is the table wich I want to insert all of my records.

```
DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [AccTransaction])

    DECLARE @Flag BIT = (SELECT IIF(@Count > 1, 1, 0))

    DECLARE @End DATETIME = GETDATE();
    DECLARE @Start DATETIME

    IF(@Flag = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Start = CAST('2021-03-08' AS DATETIME2);       
        SET @Flag = 1
    END

    ELSE IF(@Flag = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @Start = (SELECT TOP 1 EndDate FROM (SELECT EndDate FROM [AccSync] ORDER BY ActionDate DESC OFFSET 0 ROW) AS TT);
    END 

    DECLARE @RealRowCount INT = (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(@@ROWCOUNT) FROM [GetReport] (@Start, @End));
    DECLARE @TransactionCount INT = (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionCount FROM [GetReport] (@Start, @End));
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WHILE (@RealRowCount <> @TransactionCount)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @DiffDate INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Start, @End))
        
        SET @End = DATEADD(SECOND, (@DiffDate/2), @Start)

        SET @RealRowCount = (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(@@ROWCOUNT) FROM [GetReport] (@Start, @End))
        SET @TransactionCount  = (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionCount FROM [GetReport] (@Start, @End))
    END
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO [AccTransaction]
    SELECT *
    FROM [GetReport](@Start, @End)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO [AccSync]
    VALUES(NEWID(), GETDATE(), @Start, @End, ISNULL(@TransactionCount,0), DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Start, @End))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Suppose you have 10,000 records between two dates and you do not want to retrieve more than a thousand records at a time. In this case, you can use pagination. Both in the program code and in SQL.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = CAST('2021-06-02 01:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = CAST('2021-06-23 01:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)

DECLARE @RealRowCount INT = (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE InsertDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)



DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
WHILE @Counter <= @RealRowCount
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM Products
  WHERE InsertDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
  ORDER BY InsertDate
  OFFSET @Counter ROWS -- skip @Counter rows
  FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY -- take 1000 rows

  SET @Counter = @Counter + 1000
END
```

Or you can get the time difference between the two dates and add the start date each time in a specific step and retrieve the data of that date.

For example, the date difference is 20 days. Increase the start date by 5 steps each time to the start date with the end date